# How to find Last executed Query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server 2008 I need information about last run query along with its subqueries if present there. Please tell me query for that

Comment: Your answer probably appears in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849091/sql-server-2005-query-history)

Answer (score 1):

Get "Who is Active" by Adam Machanic:

http://whoisactive.com

http://whoisactive.com

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER ( session_id [ , request_id ])
[WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Current session is `@@SPID`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187730.aspx