# SQL Server 2005 Query History

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I can easily see a list of recently run queries using the following SQL:

```
SELECT      deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
            dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

This query returns 8,500 rows - all queries executed against the DB today.

**Question:** Is there any way to see the queries run against the DB for the entire week? How about for a specific day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` is reset every time SQL Server is restarted. So if you're only seeing a day's worth of data, the server must have been reset about that long ago.

Comment: Or the plan cache was flushed due to memory pressure, `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` etc.