# SQL Server receives and runs a query with wrong result

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an ASP.NET project connecting to a database. A web page sends a query to the database. More than one, as a matter of fact, it reads from database successfully.
On click of a submit button I send an `UPDATE` query to the SQL Server (2008).

I work with C#, sending the `UPDATE` query to the server with a `SqlCommand` object initialized as such:

**Edit:** Added variables to query.

```
string strQuery = "UPDATE [tbl] SET [f1]='" + stringValue + "', [f2]='" + (boolValue?"1":"0") + "' WHERE [id]=" + intId.ToString() + ";";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connectionObject);
int QueryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

QueryResult ends up 0, and, of course, no change done. Copy-Paste to SSMS - I get `1 row(s) affected` and the data changes.

Connection works fine - when I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849091/sql-server-2005-query-history) to check the work on the DB - the query has been executed. (It looks something like `(@1 varchar(8000), @2 varchar(8000), @3 tinyInt) UPDATE [tbl] SET [f1]=@1, [f2]=@2 WHERE [id]=@3;`).

Any idea what's going on - appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: may be you could show more code. May be you have a transaction that was not committed

Comment: @tunmisefasipe, Made a small edit, but in essence - that's the code.

Comment: Where does `connectionObject` come from? Also (having seen edit) please go and read about parameters, and switch to using those instead. String concatenation is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, initialized earlier. But it works - also for an `INSERT` query on the same page.

Comment: for what its worth, would recommend you change your code to use SQL parameters - will help protect you from SQL injection. Compiling strings like this is a classic way to get caught by it.

Comment: My guess would be that, *at the time that the query is constructed*, `intId` doesn't have the value that you think it has.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Bingo. I would never have guessed, apparently the Id wasn't initialized when it should have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely thing is that the `WHERE [id]=" + intId.ToString()` isn't finding the row to be updated.

Either this is because:

- The ID is correct and the row doesn't exist yet (if you're inserting it just before hand)
- The ID is wrong
- stringValue contains something that is corrupting your SQL such that it executes but matches nothing (unlikely but possible).
- You're not executing the SQL against the right database (I've done this before in Dev environments with multiple dbs around!)

If you put a breakpoint on the line after the `strQuery` assignment see what it contains, and maybe post its contents back into your question.

Comment: Got it right (a bit after DTU in comments above). Thanks for parameter advice as well - will do. (Though, this is a private system foe administrators, but it's good security practice)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to use the parameters

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connectionObject;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", stringValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", boolValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", intId);
            cmd.CommandText = "update [tbl] set f1 = @f1 , f2 = @f2 where id = @id";
            int QueryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```